# Segoe UI Hebrew/Arabic characters

Tags: fonts, windows-10

I can enter Hebrew characters in the Google search field and they are displayed correctly. For some reasons, I sometimes switch to Bing search, and now I see that I can enter Hebrew characters, but they are displayed as boxes only.

If I remove 'Segoe UI' from font-family css entry, it is displayed correctly, so Segoe UI is missing Hebrew characters on my (German) Windows 10. I can't remember whether this was the case on Windows 7, but I think it wasn't, possibly because Segoe UI wasn't installed on the system.

Korean works, Chinese seems to work (I didn't try all symbols), Japanese seems to work as well. In Arabic there are some characters missing as well (while others are displayed correctly).

Can I get an extended Segoe UI with the missing characters somewhere? How else could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Chrome? This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516209) in Chrome on Windows 10; it appears that Segoe UI no longer covers all the scripts that it used to, and Chrome hasn't yet added all the required fallback fonts.

As a temporary workaround, find *Disable DirectWrite* (`chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write`) in Chrome's flags page and *enable* the flag (you'll be enabling a negative flag, and hence disabling DirectWrite—confusingly enough.)